# Angular Ng2TelInput - Store the country code/dial code in a variable

Tags: angular

I'm finding a way to store the country dial code in a variable. Is there any way for the same. I tried implementing in onCountryChange() method. But it gives the output as event. How do we extract the dial code and store in a variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
const countryCode = event.target.value;
```

Comment: This is certainly lacking some explanation and context. Please do not answer with just one line of code. Explain your thoughts.